# How do I complete the Assignment DEATH FROM BELOW?

Tags: battlefield-4

The assignment says, `Destroy 5 attack air vehicles with Rocket Launchers`  Do all rocket launchers count?*  Does the enemy have to be present in the vehicle when you blow it up with a rocket?**

**I could have swore I already have a few kills on choppers with AA rockets*

***You still get vehicle destroy points when you blow up a vehicle, after an enemy leaves the vehicle...*

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if you have to get all 5 in a round.. Your screenshot also indicates that you do not have Naval Strike, maybe it won't start counting until that criteria is met? If you do have it, maybe you'll just have to wait for battlelog to sync.

Comment: @turbo I have premium, so we have early access to Naval Strike Assignments.    Why it doesnt show the green check mark?  Unsure, as other players have already unlocked the AA Mine.

Comment: I just checked my battlelog and mine appears unchecked as well (have premium). However, I haven't had the time to play or download the DLC to my PS4 yet, so that could be why.

Comment: I got my AA mine, and I think, that for me this counter incremented with kills with stinger. Also text may refer to Attack Helicopters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took me a while to unlock as I wasn't sure what it classed as "Attack Air Vehicles" but I'm now certain that this means scout heli, attack heli, stealth and attack jet, just not the transport chopper. You can use all rocket launcher, including Stinger and IGLA, however I used a combination of the SRAW and the Battle Pickup the HVM-II which is excellent for using against air vehicles.

Since the minor update you cannot carry AA Mines and a rocket launcher any more, so if you carry AA mines you are restricted to SLAMS, AT Mines, and the Repair Torch. No more Stinger and AA mine combo. This IMHO has nerfed their uselessness as I would take a SRAW anyday.